# Inclusion-Exclusion Principle Problem for 3 Sets Where Intersections are Unknown

Tags: combinatorics

> In a class of 30 children, 20 take Latin, 14 take Greek, and 10 take
>   Hebrew. If no child takes all three languages and eight children take
>   no language, how many children take Greek and Hebrew?

So we have 3 sets:

$$L, G, H$$

We are given that no child takes all three languages:

$$|L \cap G \cap H| = 0$$

And that eight children take no language:

$$|U| - |L \cup G \cup H| = 8$$

Where $U$ is the universal set (class of 30 children; $|U| = 30$). By simple algebra we can find $|L \cup G \cup H| = 22$. So here are my known quantities:

$$|L| = 20$$
$$|G| = 14$$
$$|H| = 10$$
$$|L \cap G \cap H| = 0$$
$$|L \cup G \cup H| = 22$$

By the inclusion-exclusion principle we can set up the following:

$$|L \cup G \cup H| = |L| + |G| + |H| - |L \cap G| - |L \cap H| - |G \cap H| + |L \cap G \cap H|$$

Plugging in for known quantities:

$$22 = 20 + 14 + 10 - |L \cap G| - |L \cap H| - |G \cap H| + 0$$
$$|L \cap G| + |L \cap H| + |G \cap H| = 22$$

Okay. But how can I find $|G \cap H|$ from this?

Comment: Here's a start: what is the maximum size of each of those intersections?

Comment: Well let's see: $|L \cap G| => 14$, $|L \cap H| => 10$, and $|G \cap H| => 10$ because the intersections must include elements from both sets, thus, the set with the smallest cardinality constrains the size of the intersections.

Comment: Edit: Oy, I screwed that up. Red herring. Not two extra ones, 12 extra ones right? Play with the numbers, see if anything pops out.

Comment: I don't follow.

Comment: Well, suppose the intersection of G and H is 10, does that cause problems?

Comment: Hm... $|L \cap G| + |L \cap H| + 10 = 22$. I don't see any problem. $|L \cap G|$ and $|L \cap H|$ could be less than their maxes and the algebra would work out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54726/discussion-between-arby-and-kenneth-worden).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's just think about it. We've got $30$ kids, but $8$ of them are taking no languages, so forget about them; we've got $22$ kids taking languages.

Of those $22$ kids, $14$ take Greek and $10$ take Hebrew, $14+10=24,$ so we've got **at least** $2$ kids taking Greek and Hebrew.

Since nobody takes three languages, the kids taking Greek and Hebrew can't be taking Latin. Since $20$ of the $22$ kids are taking Latin, that means **at most** $2$ are taking Greek and Hebrew.

Conclusion: exactly $2$ kids taking Greek and Hebrew.

Comment: Your solution is so much easier than mine!. :D

Answer (score 0):

So here's what Kenneth and I came up with by playing with the numbers using a Venn diagram. There are only a few ways to distribute the 22 students who take 2 classes amongst the three intersections.

First note $|L\cap G|+|L\cap H|+|G\cap H|=22$ and $|L\cap G \cap H|=0$ as above.

Also $|L\cap H|+|G\cap H|\le |H|=10$ because both intersections are in $H$. Putting this into $|L\cap G|+|L\cap H|+|G\cap H|=22$, we get $|L\cap G|\ge 12$.

$|L\cap G|+|G\cap H|\le |G|=14$ implies $|L\cap G|\le 14$.

Combining, we have $12\le |L\cap G|\le14$. Also note $|L\cap G|+|L\cap H|\le 20$.

If $|L\cap G|=14$, then $|G\cap H|=0$ and $|L\cap H|=10$, but that's impossible as it would mean $|L\cap G|+|L\cap H|=24$. If $|L\cap G|=13$, then $|G\cap H|=0\  or\ 1$ and $|L\cap H|=9\ or \ 8$ respectively. This is impossible as it would mean $|L\cap G|+|L\cap H|=22\ or \ 21$ respectively.

Finally we reach $|L\cap G|=12$. In this case, $|G\cap H|=0\,\ ,1\   or\ 2$ and $|L\cap H|=10,\ 9,\ or \ 8$ respectively. The first two cases again make $|L\cap G|+|L\cap H|$ too large, leaving the final possibility, $|L\cap G|=12$, $|G\cap H|=2$, and $|L\cap H|=8$ which works and is the only case which does.

All this finally gives the answer: two students take both Greek and Hebrew.